# Clio refresh token is getting expires after 30 days

Tags: clio-api

I have a scenario where I'm integrating Clio API with another API for communicating. It's mentioned in the Clio API documentation that the refresh token is for a lifetime but getting expires after 30 days. Can anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 1):

The clio `access_token` expires after 30 days. You need to add code that checks the `expires_in` date before each call, and if it is expired, you use the `refresh_token` to request a new `access_token` (where you will receive a new `refresh_token`).

See the this doc section for more details:
https://app.clio.com/api/v4/documentation#section/Authorization-with-OAuth-2.0/Oauth-Refresh-Tokens